# Change upload directory in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

Can anyone tell me about how to change upload directory without touching wp-config.php in WordPress?

Answer (score 0):

You need to go in wp-config.php and and set upload path:
define( 'UPLOADS', 'wp-content/'.'files' );

If you want the upload directory outside of wp-content you need to set upload path in wp-config.php like this: 
define( 'UPLOADS', ''.'files' );

Answer (score 0):

For same issue i used this manual [link](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/wordpress-custom-upload-dir/)

Hope it will be helpful for you

Comment: I want my wp plugin use that folder only example wp-content->uploads->docs, for other other upload it goes normally to folder uploads->2016->...

Comment: Unfortunately I do not know a ready solution for this. But I assume that using the standard wp loader you will not do so. You must write your own

Answer (score 0):

let's say you upload a picture. After you upload it, you can view the file at something like:

```
example.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/picture.png
```

And let's say you now change the uploads folder location via:

Now you need to change in `wp-config.php`

```
define('UPLOADS', 'wp-content/media');
```

This will give you a `URL` like this:

```
example.org/wp-content/media/2014/12/picture.png
```

Hope this will help!